# php switching to mysqli: num_rows issue

Tags: php, mysqli

I recently started updating some code to MySQL improved extension, and have been successful up until this point:

```
// old code - works
$result = mysql_query($sql);
    if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysql_fetch_array($result);
    echo $row['data'];
    }


// new code - doesn't work
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); 
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    echo $row['data'];
    }
```

As shown I am trying to use the **object oriented style**.
I get no mysqli error, and vardump says no data... but there definitely is data in the db table.

Comment: Is your `$mysqli` connection object successfully connected? You haven't checked errors.  `if (!$result) echo $mysqli->error;`

Comment: Do a `var_dump()` on $mysqlli, $result and $row. You'll find the error

Comment: var dumps are saying no data... but there is definitely content in the table.

Comment: If you are already switching, switching to using [PDO](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) might save you a lot of trouble.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this:

```
<?php

// procedural style

$host = "host";
$user = "user";
$password = "password";
$database = "db";

$link = mysqli_connect($host, $user, $password, $database);

IF(!$link){
    echo ('unable to connect to database');
}

ELSE {
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link,$sql);
    if(mysqli_num_rows($result) == 1){
    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result, MYSQLI_BOTH);
    echo $row['data'];
    }
}
mysqli_close($link);


// OOP style 

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table LIMIT 1";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); /* I have added the suggestion from Your Common Sence */
    if($result->num_rows == 1) {
    $row = $result->fetch_array();
    echo $row['data'];
    }

    $mysqli->close() ;

// In the OOP style if you want more than one row. Or if you query contains more rows.    

$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);
$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table";
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]"); /* I have added the suggestion from Your Common Sence */
    while($row = $result->fetch_array()) {
     echo $row['data']."<br>";
    }

    $mysqli->close() ;    

?>
```

Comment: First, why would this make a difference? Second, your `mysqli_query()` call is missing its first parameter.

Comment: Third, `MYSQLI_BOTH` is the default parameter, so you changed nothing. :)

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski the difference is that the OP is familiar with the procedural style anyway.

Comment: @AshwinMukhija I didn't know the mysqli_both was used by default. Doesn't hurt if the OP uses it.

Comment: I didnt use a while loop because I am only fetching one table row once. So i thought this would be a better way, no?

Comment: Hi, did the query yield any results when you used the procedural style. If that is the case you have data and you have no errors from your db. Then the next step is to check the your OOP writing style. I have very little experience in OOP programming. However, I will give it a try for you. The while loop was to make sure that you didn't get more than row return. In that case the query would not be execute because you only want to execute when you have one row of date. With limit you limited you results to row even if the first part of the query yield more data rows.

Comment: neither the first nor second works for me. I get no mysqli error, and vardump says no data... but there definitely is data in the db table. I dont understand.

Comment: I do believe that MySQLi requires a `while` loop when fetching even a single result, like: `while($row = $result->fetch()) {}` but I might be wrong.

Comment: @Gargron I haven't tested it, but by limiting to one row it will work for sure. I guess you would get the first row if you do it without a loop, because you would do the same thing as limiting the while loop execution to one cycle.

Comment: @user1938102 could you provide your exact mysql query ($sql). And table structure? B.T.W. I made a edit in which I changed email which was in my database a column name to data. Try that first.

Comment: @Gargron fetching a single row is just `->fetch[_assoc]()`. Think of it as MySQLdb (python)'s `cursor.fetchone()`

Comment: just out of curiosity, which is a better practice in this case, using a while loop with limit or the method in the example?

Comment: It depends but I would think that is better to use while with a limit in the SQL. Because you can then recycle the code in another case where you need to retrieve all the data. In that case you could copy the code in my post and just change the query. B.T.W. if you just want 1 column it would be better to select only that column (SELECT data FROM data_table LIMIT 1).

Comment: @user1938102 did my code work this time. Or do you still have problems.

Comment: ok thanks for the tip. Yeah i figured out the problem, was a typo elsewhere in the script. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

As it was said, you're not checking for the errors.
Run all your queries this way

```
$result = $mysqli->query($sql) or trigger_error($mysqli->error." [$sql]");
```

if no errors displayed and var dumps are saying no data - then the answer is simple: your query returned no data. Check query and data in the table.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP v 5.2 mysqli::num_rows is not set before fetching data rows from the query result:

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($host,$user, $password, $database);

if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
    trigger_error(sprintf(
        'Cannot connect to database. Error %s (%s)',
        $mysqli->connect_error,
        $mysqli->connect_errno
    ));
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM data_table";

$result = $mysqli->query($sql);

// a SELECT query will generate a mysqli_result
if ($result instanceof mysqli_result) {
    $rows = array();
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $rows[] = $row;
    }

    $num_rows = $result->num_rows; // or just count($rows);

    $result->close();

    // do something with $rows and $num_rows
} else {
    //$result will be a boolean
}

$mysqli->close() ;
```