# Why isn't num_rows returning any value?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following PHP code where I want to return the number of rows based on the previous SQL statement, however, $num doesn't doesn't seem to be returning anything.

```
$ipAddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];

if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM whovisit WHERE ipAddress = ".$ipAddress."")) {
    $num = $result->num_rows;
}
echo $num; // <-- not showing up on my page

if ($num > 0) {
    $sqlupdate = $mysqli->query("UPDATE whovisit SET visitCount = visitCount + 1 WHERE ipAddress = ".$ipaddress."");
}
else {
    $sqlupdate = $mysqli->query("INSERT INTO whovisit values ('".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."', '1')");
}
```

Any ideas? Thanks

Comment: Getting the IP address, you use `$ipaddress` and in your query you use `$ipAddress` with an uppercase A. The points in the answers about needing quotes around the IP address in your queries are also correct.

Comment: @BurningLights I didn't see that and it appears to be gone now - possibly a bad copy/paste?

Comment: @BurningLights sorry, I typed that variable after on the site and forgot to capitalize it. Its capitalized in my code. Its the quotes that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ensure that you have a $ infront of ipaddress

```
$ipaddress = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
```

As the IP address is a string it should be put in single quotes.

```
if ($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM whovisit WHERE ipAddress = '".$ipAddress."';")) {
    $num = $result->num_rows;
}
```

If you are unsure if the query is running correctly you could also add an else to the above if statment and output any mysql error messages.

```
}else{
    echo "QueryError: ".$mysqli->error
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you get nothing on the page, this means `$num` must not be being set. Given the code you have, that would mean the `if` block is not being executed - i.e. `$result` is a falsey value. Which means your query is failing.

And unfortunately this one's pretty easy if you examine the generated query. Following what happens step-by-step, we see you're injecting the contents of the server variable `REMOTE_ADDR`, which is presumably going to be an IPv4 address in a dotted-decimal format, into the query string. So you'll have a SQL statement like, which fails to parse at the second `.`:

```
SELECT * FROM whovisit WHERE ipAddress = 127.0.0.94
```

Oops.

---

Since the IP address is a string, you need to enclose it in single quotes:

```
"SELECT * FROM whovisit WHERE ipAddress = '".$ipAddress."'"
```

Which will result in the queries in the following form:

```
SELECT * FROM whovisit WHERE ipAddress = '127.0.0.94'
```

Or better yet, use a parameterized query and you don't have to worry about quoting and escaping. `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is probably relatively safe as far as SQL injection attacks go, but 1)it's easier to use parameters than a concatenated string, and 2)you never *truly* can trust a value you didn't generate yourself.

Answer (score 0):

Similar post:

[php switching to mysqli: num_rows issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14917447/php-switching-to-mysqli-num-rows-issue)

In PHP v 5.2 mysqli::num_rows is not set before fetching data rows from the query result.